# how to console.log before prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, prompt

How to avoid this stupid behaviour - `prompt dialog` brakes the code I need to decide what to enter into the dialog.

In this case that's the console.log.  How to get `prompt` dialog **after** console is written.

```js
$('.selx').on('change', function(){
  let a = $(this).val();
  console.log(a);
  let b = prompt('NEW TITLE');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='selx'>
<option value='323'>lorem</option>
<option value='525'>ipsum</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `prompt` blocks - the stack snippet console hasn't had time to re-render before the `prompt` prevents anything further from occurring. Put the `prompt` in a `setTimeout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console is asynchronous (there is always a small delay, usually you won't notice it). Calling `prompt` will halt everything else going on on the tab, including the console. Therefore you have to add a small delay to enable the browser updating the console before prompting:

```
 $('.selx').on('change', function(){
   let a = $(this).val();
   console.log(a);
   setTimeout(() => {
      let b = prompt('NEW TITLE');
   }, 10);
 });
```

Comment: ans what if my code is not just `console.log` but a heavy function? How can I be sure that timeout of 10 or any - is enough?

Comment: @puerto what do you mean with "heavy" ? the timeout will be started when the line with `setTimeout` is reached, meaning that all previous lines were executed already.

Comment: Oh, if so - that's ok. Thanks a lot. Let's say - solved.

Comment: @puerto glad to help :)

Comment: @JonasWilms Why do you need a `10` timeout? Wouldn't `0` work just as well?

Comment: @nik probably, actually I chose that randomly :)