# Why the program does not log the results of the function before asking the user if he/she wants to enter more numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, prompt

I have a function `calculator()`. The calculator prompts the user to enter a series of numbers, which are then registered in an array and performs the four main arithmetic operations with all of them (+, -, *, /), loggin the results in the console.

I want to ask if it wants to perform more operations with other numbers so I have done this:

```js
function calculator () {
  
  let input = prompt(), arr = [];

  while (input !== null) {
  arr.push(input)
  input = prompt();
  }
  
  arr = arr.map(x => x.trim()); 
  arr = arr.filter(y => y !== ""); 
  let arrBoolean = arr.map(element => Boolean(+element)),
      check = arrBoolean.every(value => value);
      
  if (arr.length > 0) {
    if (arr.length > 1) {
      if (check) {
        arr = arr.map(index => +index);
        let results = [];
        let signs = [" + ", " - ", " * ", " / "];
        let sum = 0, deduct = arr[0], mult = 1, div = +arr[0] == 1 ? 1 : +arr[0] * 2;
        for (let add of arr) {
          sum += add;
        }
        
        for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
          deduct -= arr[i];
        }
        
        for (let rept of arr) {
          mult *= rept;
        }
        for (let fract of arr) {
          div /= fract;
        }
        results.push(sum, deduct, mult, div);
        
        for (let s = 0; s < signs.length; s++) {
          console.log(`${arr.join(signs[s])} = ${Number.isInteger(results[s]) ? results[s] : results[s].toFixed(3)}`);
        }
        
        
      } else {console.log("Non numerical value")}
      
    } else {check ? Number.isInteger(Math.sqrt(arr[0])) ? console.log(`√${arr[0]} = ${Math.sqrt(arr[0])}`) : console.log(`√${arr[0]} = ${Math.sqrt(arr[0]).toFixed(3)}`) : console.log("Non numerical value");}
   

  } else {console.log("Missing arguments")}

}

let repeat = true;

while (repeat !== null) {
  console.log(calculator());
  repeat = prompt("¿Desea introducir más números?");
}
```

The problem is that this block does not log the results to the console before asking the user, but asks the user repeatedly until it cancels.

It is a headache because if the user for example wants to perform operations with nine series of numbers, it will ask the user nine times before logging the results, instead of logging them as he/she enters the input.

Comment: Can you please create a [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) of your issue so we can see the problem for ourselves easier and debug your problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to console.log before prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53969525/how-to-console-log-before-prompt)

Comment: @NickParsons I have already done it.